How to Efficiently Optimize a Python Script for Processing Large CSV Files?
I’ve been working on a Python script to process large CSV files (500MB to 1GB). The script performs tasks like filtering rows based on column values, calculating new fields, and exporting the processed data to another CSV file. While the functionality works fine, the script becomes significantly slower as the file size increases, especially when handling files closer to 1GB.
Here’s the structure of my current script:
python
Copy code
import pandas as pd  

# Step 1: Read the CSV file  
df = pd.read_csv("large_file.csv")  

# Step 2: Filter rows  
filtered_df = df[df["column_name"] > 100]  

# Step 3: Perform calculations  
filtered_df["new_column"] = filtered_df["column_name"] * 2  

# Step 4: Export the results  
filtered_df.to_csv("filtered_output.csv", index=False)  
The main bottlenecks seem to be in the reading and filtering stages when working with large datasets.

I’ve tried several optimization techniques:
Using chunksize in pd.read_csv:
This allows processing smaller chunks of the file at a time. However, it complicates the logic for filtering and aggregating data since it requires combining results across chunks.
Switching to Dask:
I attempted using Dask for parallel processing, which improved performance to some extent. However, it feels like overkill for smaller projects, and the learning curve was steeper than expected.
Sorting the CSV file beforehand:
I sorted the file based on the filtering criteria, hoping it would speed up the filtering step. While it helped in some cases, it’s not always practical, especially when the data source is not under my control.
What I expected:
To achieve a solution that balances simplicity and performance. Ideally, I want to stick to pandas if possible but wouldn’t mind exploring other lightweight solutions.

Would you mind explaining a bit more about intended use case? I don't see a reason why chunking the file won't help you as you can essentially stream the data rather than loading it all at once into RAM. Is the problem that time-wise it takes a lot of time to process the data? Because then you will have to go parallel and the solution will no longer be as simple and neat as you want it.

The problem is that the entire input file ends up in a single dataframe. Maybe your sample code is an oversimplification but if it's a realistic example of what you're doing, don't use a dataframe. Just read the input file one line at a time (either with or without the aid of the csv module) then write to the output file as you go along.

If some of your calculations require combining different rows, you should have included an example here.  There's nothing in your sample code that couldn't be done one row at a time.

You can process data in manageable chunks its the way to go. To avoid the combining results across chunks, you can write directly to the output file.
import pandas as pd

CHUNK_SIZE = 100000


first_chunk = True
for chunk in pd.read_csv("large_file.csv", chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
    # Filter rows
    filtered = chunk[chunk["column_name"] > 100]
    
    
    filtered["new_column"] = filtered["column_name"] * 2
    
    
    filtered.to_csv("output.csv", 
                   mode='a' if not first_chunk else 'w',
                   header=first_chunk,
                   index=False)
    first_chunk = False

Note: Adjust the CHUNK_SIZE based on your available RAM and processing speed if needed

Further to my comment about dealing with this one line at a time, I suggest:
from pathlib import Path

input_file = Path("large_file.csv")
output_file = Path("filtered_output.csv")

with output_file.open("w") as data_out:
    with input_file.open() as data_in:
        columns = next(data_in).strip().split(",") + ["new_column"]
        ci = columns.index("column_name")
        print(",".join(columns), file=data_out)
        for values in map(lambda line: line.strip().split(","), data_in):
            colval = int(values[ci])
            if colval > 100:
                values.append(str(colval*2))
                print(",".join(values), file=data_out)

Given these input data:
a,b,c,column_name,d,e,f
1,2,3,200,5,6,7
2,2,3,4,5,6,7
3,2,3,300,5,6,7
4,2,3,400,5,6,7

The code would generate:
a,b,c,column_name,d,e,f,new_column
1,2,3,200,5,6,7,400
3,2,3,300,5,6,7,600
4,2,3,400,5,6,7,800

Memory usage will be low. You can also expect this to perform well.
It is assumed in this code that the value associated with "column_name" is an integer.
